# If a rental contract does not specify method of payment, can a tenant abruptly opt to begin offering to pay by cash only?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules

Suppose a contract specifies an amount for monthly payment and the tenant pays on time each month for the first two months and then abruptly decides to offer the landlord who lives in anther city the option to collect the owed rent in cash from the rental address if they want to receive it.

Is there any way in which the tenant is now committing a violation of the tenancy?

I suppose even if not it is still wise not to troll one's landlords and keep them happy even on discretionary matters because once the tenancy reaches statutory periodic phase then they can always send a section 21 without any deeper explanation if they're at all unhappy with the tenant for any reason.

Still curious though.

Comment: Not that it helps, but this sounds like an oversight on the part of the landlord. It's common in the UK for the tenancy agreement to specify that rent is paid by standing order in advance, which rules out any other form of payment (unless separately agreed otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usual for a lease or other rental agreement to specify where payment is to be made, often the landlord's business address. If it does so specify, that provision controls unless it is so unreasonable that a court would void it. Similarly, a rental agreement may specify the acceptable forms of payment. If it does, that provision controls unless it is very unreasonable.

It was once customary for the landlord, or the landlord's agent, to call in person to collect rent on a regular basis. But this has not been the usual practice for a long time.

If the lease does not specify how or where the rent must be paid, it is up to the tenant to make sure that it reaches the landlord. Mailing a check or money order is a common way to do this. If the tenant delivers cash to the landlord in person, or mails it by registered mail, so that it is relatively safe from loss, that should be sufficient. But the risk of loss in the mail is on the tenant.

A tenant would be wise to obtain a written receipt for any cash payments.

Answer (score 1):

### The tenant has to pay the landlord

The landlord is not obliged to collect the rent. So long as the tenant drives to the other city and pays the landlord it can be in cash.